# Retrieve sub set from IEnumerable<>

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I have a complex structure of entities of following structure

**EDIT**

[image]

These categories are added in cache by `IEnumerable<Category>`

I have to return the category hierarchy with titles only to required language say English.

Can anyone let me know how to do it?

Comment: Can you give example of sample input, output ?

Comment: example means ? i have to filter the list based on LanguageID. say filter for TransCategory, and TransSubCategory

Comment: How does your starting data look like, and what do you want your function to accomplish. Just a text with what you begin with, and how do you want it to look like after you filter it. I am not entirely able to understand what the end result should look like

Comment: Category has category ID, TransCategory has CategoryID,LanguageID,Title: row 1 = 1|1|Arts, Row 2= 1|2|الفنون. I want to get Category record and only row 1 (LanguageID) from TransCategory

Comment: the above one is simple, problem occurs when i have to take TransSubCategories. The hierarchy is Category -> Subcategories->TransSubcategory

Comment: hey i have uploaded the ERD

Answer (score 0):

If your desire is to filter the list and be left with IEnumerable of categories that:
 1. Have at least one TransCategory with languageId = "english" 
 2. Have at least one SubCategory that has at least one TransSubCategory with languageId = "english" 
then:

```
//categories are a IEnumerable<Category> already populated
categories = categories.Where(c => c.TransCategories.Any(ct => ct.LanguageID == "english") || 
c.SubCategories.Any(sc => sc.TransSubCategories.Any(tsc => tsc.LanguageID == "english") );
```

If you want to keep your categories list the same, however in the SubCategories and TransCategories lists to keep only those that have languageId = 1, then:

```
foreach (var category in categories)
{
   category.TransCategories = category.TransCategories.Where(tc => tc.LanguageID == 1);
   foreach (var subCategory in category.SubCategories)
   {
      subCategory.TransSubCategories = subCategory.TransSubCategores.Where(tsc => tsc.LanguageID == 1);
   }
}
```

This should filter out all transCategories and transSubCategores that dont have languageId == 1. However think carefully about your border cases. Meaning when you dont have a transCategory that has LanguageID == 1 in your category.TransCategores you will most likely recieve an empty IEnumerable there (not 100% sure but it should be like that, test it)  and the same case with the category.SubCategories.TransSubCategories. So worst case scenario you would get an List with empty IEnumerables in SubCategories.

I didnt have where to test it so you should be a little sceptical. Also if there is a mistake or you want to achieve something different, let me know. Sorry for not being able to be more helpful

---

If you dont want to change your categories than you simply get it in another object: /* Please note that IEnumerable doesnt support clone and you cant get a pure copy of categories, but we can get a separate instance by calling it as a List */

```
var userCategories = categories.ToList();
foreach (var category in userCategories)
{
   category.TransCategories = category.TransCategories.Where(tc => tc.LanguageID == 1);
   foreach (var subCategory in category.SubCategories)
   {
      subCategory.TransSubCategories = subCategory.TransSubCategores.Where(tsc => tsc.LanguageID == 1);
   }
}
```

So this should have the results you want inside userCategories, while categories will be unchanged. You should also keep in mind that calling .ToList() will enumerate your object if you are using IQueryable and such. 
 Quote from MSDN:

> The ToList(IEnumerable) method forces immediate
>   query evaluation and returns a List that contains the query
>   results. You can append this method to your query in order to obtain a
>   cached copy of the query results.

However you should test what Im telling you because I dont have a place to test it yet. 
Hope this helps you

Comment: thanks for your efforts, but still it doesn't return what i need. Surely i am unable to explain my question. ok let's take it simple. Can you write me a linq query in which i can take a complete list of Categories but Transcategories only for english language? say trans category have 2 records for each category, i need only one in which languageID = 1

Comment: So you want to get the same categories, but Inside their SubCategories and TransCategories, to remain only those that have languageId = 1 ? 
Simplified you want to remove those Subcategories and TransCategories that dont have languageId = 1 ?

Comment: you are correct, that's what i want but not remove other Trans(s), this category hierarchy is cached on my server and for every user i just return the required language based data.

Comment: In this case rather than overriding your current categories create new objects and assign the filtered results to them

Comment: i don't want to override current categories, just want to take a filtered copy of current (from Cache and it will remain in cache for other languages) and return that new category list that is in fact filtered out from exisitng